# Xerces: Get the raw XML for a particular DOMElement

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, xerces-c

I am using Xerces-C **DOMLSParser** to parse an XML Input source, and get a **DOMDocument** tree. I am navigating to a particular **DOMElement**. I wish to get the original raw XML markup for that element and its sub-elements.

For an XML such as the following:

```
<positionreport>
  <config lastupdate="1114600280"> 
    <login user="some name" password="cleartext" />
    <reports>
     <report tab="1" name="Report One" />
     <report tab="2" name="Report Two" />
     <report tab="3" name="Third Report" />
     <report tab="4" name="Fourth Report" />
     <report tab="5" name="Fifth Report" />
    </reports>
  </config>
</positionreport>
```

I get a DOMDocument from [DOMLSParser::parse()](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMLSParser.html#a45ea6b19b11ffb1aebd2fa24ffed5026) and let's say that I navigate to the DOMElement corresponding to the element '**Reports**'. How can I generate the raw XML string for this node i.e.:

```
<reports>
 <report tab="1" name="Report One" />
 <report tab="2" name="Report Two" />
 <report tab="3" name="Third Report" />
 <report tab="4" name="Fourth Report" />
 <report tab="5" name="Fifth Report" />
</reports>
```

Is there any way to do this? If it cannot be done from *DOMElement, DOMDocument, DOMLSParser*, is there any way I can do this using any other types without having to serialize again?

My current plan is to read in the XML file as a character stream, and regex-match the required substring based on the required XML tags. I do not prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Xerces much, but I would assume you have to serialize the DOMElement/DOMNode in order to get its raw XML markup:

```
virtual XMLCh* DOMLSSerializer::writeToString(const DOMNode * nodeToWrite, MemoryManager * manager = NULL)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, writeToString is not properly defined for nodes other than DOMDocument and DOMEntity. It is okay to use it for debugging purposes.